# Discount for emails with specific domain

Tags: commerce

I am trying to apply a discount automatically for customers who sign up using emails from partner companies.
I tried using the conditions section with * or % as a wildcard, but that did not work
[image: commerce_discount_condition]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the current state of the plugin (`OrderEmail`) that provides this condition. It uses an email element, meaning the Drupal Forms API will validate input to ensure it's an email address, ruling out any sort of wildcard inclusion. I'm going to open a feature request against the module, as I believe converting this to a textfield and revising `OrderEmail::evaluate()` to support wildcard matching can be implemented in a backwards compatible fashion.

Feedback welcome, as I'm not sure if we should support more than just a leading wildcard to match against any address from a specific domain or support more complex arrangements:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3390184